# Stop service "handler loop code" doesn't work

Tags: android, service

I readed all similar questions and tried them, but I can't solve my problem. I create a service , this service show toast message every 5sec. But I can't stop this service. Could you please help me to fix or different way? Thank you.

```
public class myservice extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    go2sec();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void go2sec() {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(myservice.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            go2sec();
        }
    }, 5000);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

--- Mainactivity ---

I can start service;

```
startService(new Intent(this, myservice.class));
```

**But, I can't stop service;**

```
stopService(new Intent(this, myservice.class));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the handler callback in your service . And call `stopSelf()` in service to stop it.

Here is the code:

```
  public class Myservice extends Service {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        go2sec();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(Myservice.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            go2sec();
        }
    };

    private void go2sec() {
        handler.postDelayed(task, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(task);   //remove handler
        stopSelf();    //stop the service
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad but "stopService();" doesn't work again ?

Comment: you are wlcome...happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop your handler.

You have to call `removeCallbacks` on your `handler` in the `onDestroy` method.

This should stop your service properly.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution :

```
    public class VolumeService extends Service  {
        boolean running;
        Thread t;

        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Log.d("service destroyed", "destroyed");
            running = false;
            super.onDestroy();
        }
       @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        running = true;
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (running) {

                        if ("check your condition when you want to start the job") {
                            Log.d("Service", "Service:Started");
                            try {
                                startJob();
                                waitForSometime();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            t.interrupt();
                            Log.d("ServiceStop", "Service:Stopped");
                            running = false;
                        }

                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startJob() {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

               // your logic / business implementation
            }
        });
    }


    }
```